# Libraries overview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, aar

I have to use few *.aar libraries in my android project.

I have already added definition of the folder which contains all libraries to the build.gradle and everything wokrs fine.

But the thing I have a problem with is actually to find out which libraries I am actually using in my project. 
So, the questions are:

- Is it possible to find out which libraries are referenced in a project in Android Studio?
- Is there any place where I can actually manage libraries referenced in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio

File -- >Project Structure --> select module -- > select "dependencies" Tab

Comment: Is it just possible to add or remove libraries from there?

Comment: It shows the list of referenced libraries in your app

Comment: Is it possible to find all the places in the project files where it have been used?

Comment: you cannot do with the library as a whole , you can find where the methods of the libraries are referenced by selecting the method and doing "find usages"